# Create and return pdf with images using Aspnet.core

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, backend

I have an Aspnet.core backend application which serves as an API for some frontend. I'm trying to create a pdf file which contains some images in byte array format and some captions for the images. Finally, I want the pdf to be returned when somebody sends a request to the api. Using libraries that require html and css to create pdfs or some intricate configurations is an overkill, I want to do it in the simplest and the most primitive way possible with no regard to formatting apart from font size and text alignment.

I have tried using aspose.pdf but demo license doesn't let me create more than 4 pages and that's not enough. When trying to add an image it doesn't work anyway.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPDF(/*some arguments*/)
        {
            /*
            Here I get images (as byte arrays) and captions from the
            database

            Then I want to create a pdf and loop over the images and
            alternate adding a caption and an image to the pdf
            */
            using (var streamPdf = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Next line saves pdf to memorystream so it can be sent
                document.Save(streamPdf);
                return File(streamPdf.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked out `pdfsharp`? or `itextsharp`?

Comment: @RyanWilson I think the license changed for `itextsharp` so it's no longer free to use, or something along those lines

Comment: @Dortimer You just need to get `itextsharp` version `4.1.6`, it was the last version with a free licensing. here's a download link (https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/)